# JS Files not able to import typescript file using non-relative imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am writing configuration file(runner.test.js)  to run my test cases. I have project which has .js,.ts,.tsx,.jsx files. Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Problem Statement:
A relative import is working for .ts file but non-relative imports are not working when imported from js files.

```
import { SubApplicationType } from 'midfx/types/types.ts'; ( non-relative imports not work )
import { SubApplicationType } from '../midfx/types/types.ts'; ( relative import is working. Notice  ../ in import statement)
```

All my .ts files are being imported as non-relative imports. I cannot change all the import statement to relative import.

What change i need to do so that non-relative imports works for .ts files when imported from .js files.

My project structure is

```
src-
    midfx
         types
            types.ts
```

I am running command [ node runner.test.js ]. I am setting properties for the typescript under require('ts-node').register()

```js
Source Code runner.test.js:
const path = require('path');
const mockCssModules = require('mock-css-modules');

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'test';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const mock = require('mock-require');

require('@babel/register');

//TSconfig.js options are made in this method.

require('ts-node').register({
  compilerOptions: {
    allowJs: true,
    baseUrl: "./src",
    paths: { 
      "src/*": ["*"],
      "midfx/*": ["midfx/*"]
    },
  },
  transpileOnly: true,
  files: true,
});

require('jsdom-global')();

const Mocha = require('mocha');
const glob = require('glob');

const mocha = new Mocha({});
const fs = require('fs');

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);
const appFolder = resolveApp('src');



glob(`${appFolder}/**/*.js`, {}, (err, paths) => {
  paths.forEach(f => {
    const p = f.replace(`${appFolder}/`, '');
    const p1 = p.replace('.js', '');
    mock(p, f);
    mock(p1, f);
  });
});


glob(`${appFolder}/**/*.ts`, {}, (err, paths) => {
    paths.forEach(f => {
    const p = f.replace(`${appFolder}/`, '');
    const p1 = p.replace('.ts', '');
    mock(p, f);
    mock(p1, f);
  });
});

glob(`${appFolder}/**/*.tsx`, {}, (err, paths) => {
  console.log(`tsx folders paths = ${paths.length}`);
  paths.forEach(f => {
    const p = f.replace(`${appFolder}/`, '');
    const p1 = p.replace('.tsx', '');
    mock(p, f);
    mock(p1, f);
  });
});


glob(`${appFolder}/reducers/**/*.spec.js`, {}, (err, allTestFiles) => {
  allTestFiles.forEach((file) => {
    mocha.addFile(file);
  });

  mocha.run(failures => {
    process.on('exit', () => {
      process.exit(failures ? 1 : 0);
    });
  });
});
```

Regards
ilikeflex

Comment: Is been be related to tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `baseUrl` in your *tsconfig.json* file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Comment: @konard, @kurt, I tried using "baseurl". I am setting the content of tsconfig.json in `require('ts-node').register()` code above. How to debug if the baseurl is making any change?